# Reputation query doesn't match that on SO

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

This morning, at 2011-04-06 00:22:38Z, I received a question upvote for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027999/c-5-async-ctp-why-is-internal-state-set-to-0-in-generated-code-before-endawai). That shows up as giving me 5 reputation when looking at the Stack Overflow reputation page.

However, when I use the JSON API, I don't see that question. I see everything else (including an answer which got an upvote at 00:26:12Z, suggesting that it's not the fromDate parameter which is incorrect). Any idea why the question vote doesn't show?

URL I'm using:

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/22656/reputation?fromdate=1302048000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that query got broken and just wasn't returning question sourced rep gains, ever.

This has been fixed.